# How to upload a file from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the presigned url of an object that belongs to a s3 bucket I can use the link to download the object but I want that object to be added in my own s3 bucket. Is there any way to do this directly?

Comment: I doubt that is possible with something like a `CopyObject` command because for that to work you need credentials that have reading permissions on one object and writing permissions for the other. Credentials from a pre-signed URL do not match that requirement. You most likely have to download it and then upload it "manually".

Comment: @luk2302 yeah that's what I was also getting, it seems like there's no direct way. I wanted to achieve this without having to download it.

Comment: Well you may be able to do so with a worker in AWS, like a lambda or ecs task. Then it would stay in the aws network. Still not direct, but you would avoid some egress traffic.

Comment: @theherk depends on the bucket regions, cross-region data transfer always takes time and costs some money.

Comment: @luk2302: Yes of course, but it could still be transferred within the aws cross region private backbone, which would be lower cost and latency than using public networks. So, worst case is public networks, then cross-region via global backbone, and best case same region, I believe.